# Multiple rows in a function calculation in R

Tags: r, function

I have the following data:

```
measurement <- c(1:30)
angle <- rnorm(30, 0, 0.4)
data.1 <- data.frame(measurement, angle)
```

And I want to make a function that returns a TRUE value for four different scenarios:

```
   1. When 'angle' >  0.3 
or 2. When 'angle' < -0.3 
or 3. When 'angle' + the previous 'angle' >  0.3 
or 4. When 'angle' + the previous 'angle' < -0.3
```

I tried it with a for loop, and I've tried it the following way, but I just don't know how to include the sum of the angle and the angle that is measured one time-step earlier (so what i'm doing here is wrong but how can i improve it? preferably on the computationally least strenuous way because I work with massive data-sets):

```
n<-data.1$angle
function1 <- function(n){
    return(n>0.3 | n<(-0.3) | (n+(n-1))>(0.3) | (n+(n-1))<(-0.3))
}
```

Sorry for being an R novice but after strolling through the labyrinth of R documentation I saw no other way but to ask it here. Thanks for helping!

Comment: you're not including the previous angle. you are subtracting 1 from the current angle. your function would need two parameters the way you' re implementing it, First, the angle and Second, angle at previous index (or just index).

Comment: Thanks Arun, that was exactly what I didn't know how to do, although your solution below is definitely much more elegant. If I where to use the method I wrote, how would I have to 'parameterize' the angle at previous index? And in you method below, what is the use of the 0 in the c() function? (trying to learn the most out of it here:)

Comment: The purpose of 0 is to add it to the first element of `data.1$angle`. Since you are adding it to the previous angle, the first angle won't have a previous one. So, I add 0.

Comment: For the function.. it would have to be something like: `function(ang, ang.idx) { abs(ang) > 0.3 | abs(ang + ang[ang.idx-1]) > 0.3`. Here, I've not checked for the condition `ang.idx-1 = 0`. then ang[0] will result in integer(0) which is not the result you want. So, you'll have to take care of the condition. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: However, it is not an efficient way to do it. It is good probably to get the satisfaction of getting what you started done.

Comment: No I'll definitely use your method, it was purely out of interest on whether I was at the right track and on how to fix it otherwise, thanks again for the great answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in a vectorised format instead of doing it for each angle one by one.

```
abs(data.1$angle) > 0.3 | abs(data.1$angle + c(0, head(data.1$angle,-1))) > 0.3
```

**abs(data.1$angle) > 0.3** - the first and second conditions.
**abs(data.1$angle + c(0, head(data.1$angle,-1))) > 0.3** - takes all angles and adds the previous angle to it using `c(0, head(., -1))`. Then again check with `abs` for 0.3 and -0.3

I get:

```
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [15]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [29]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: +1. I was just trying something with `diff`, but it wasn't working out as expected.